# Javascript array and object/classes

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, object

i am trying to display three playing cards on the screen and for some reason everytime i run the code a type error appears and i have tried everything to try to fix it but nothing has worked. I think that the problem is in the array/object constructor but i think that everything is right inside of those.

```
"use strict";

function main(){
var cvs = document.getElementById("foo");
var ctx = foo.getContext("2d");
function Card(posX, posY, imgX, imgY){
    this.posX = posX;
    this.posY = posY;
    this.imgX = imgX;
    this.imgY = imgY;
    this.width = 97;
    this.height = 129;
}
Card.img = new Image();
Card.img.src = "allcards.png";
var cards = [new Card(0,0,0,0), new Card(400,400,194,258), new Card(200,200,291,387)];
var greaterX = false;
var lessX = false;
var greaterY = false;
var lessY = false;
var offsetX;
var offsetY;
setInterval(draw, 10);

function draw(){
    ctx.fillStyle="rgb(0,255,255)";
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,600,600);
    ctx.drawImage(Card.img,cards[1].imgX,cards[1].imgY,Card.width,Card.height,cards[1].posX, cards[1].posY);
    ctx.drawImage(Card.img,cards[2].imgX,cards[2].imgY,Card.width,Card.height,cards[2].posX, cards[2].posY);
}

}
```

Comment: What's the error?  One problem is that you're using Card.width and Card.height which don't look like they've been defined.

Comment: there is a typeerror that always shows up on the 3rd line in the draw function

Comment: @MarkRhodes  - The Card.width and Card.height are defined in the constructor

Comment: @CRS: No, they're not.  `cards[...].width` is defined in the constructor, but `Card.width` isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: did you want, for example, cards[1].width instead of Cards.width?  (same for height)

Comment: @user471129 i tried that too and it still errored

Comment: @cHao - does the 'this.width = 97' not count (inside the constructor)

Comment: Why do you draw in an interval of 10ms?

Comment: @CRS: Nope.  That sets `width` on the instance being created, but `(new Card(...)).width` and `Card.width` are two entirely different properties.

Answer (score 1):

var ctx = foo.getContext("2d");

should this not be

var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have confused the static properties of the `Card` function object with those of the Card instances - the `width` and `height` properties are instance properties.

```
var cvs = document.getElementById("foo");
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

function Card(posX, posY, imgX, imgY){
    this.posX = posX;
    this.posY = posY;
    this.imgX = imgX;
    this.imgY = imgY;
}
// default values/methods, accessible and overwritable on all instances:
Card.prototype.width = 97;
Card.prototype.height = 129;
Card.prototype.draw = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(Card.img, this.imgX, this.imgY, this.width, this.height, this.posX, this.posY);
};

// static property:
Card.img = new Image();
Card.img.src = "allcards.png";
Card.img.onload = draw;

var cards = [new Card(0,0,0,0), new Card(400,400,194,258), new Card(200,200,291,387)];

function draw(){
    ctx.fillStyle="rgb(0,255,255)";
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,600,600);
    for (var i=0; i<2; i++)
        cards[i].draw();
};
```